# RatingStars addon setValueCaption doesn't work on iOs

Tags: java, ios, maven, vaadin, add-on

I use [RatingStars](https://github.com/tehapo/RatingStars) addon to create rating stars on a survey of a web application. It works on a normal web browser, but the rating is messed up in iOs.

When I choose one rating, for exp, in the photo, i choose "Poor" for one question, the star caption appears properly for that particular question. When scroll down to other question, the caption follows to other stars and the ratings are automatically chosen. I didn't click on a star of the below question, the star is automatically chosen because the caption follows my scroll.

I was thinking thats its a css problem, but I checked the css styles, and the divs appeared to be in proper width and height

Also, sometime i didn't choose any rating, I simply scroll down and the ratings are automatically chosen. maybe something to do with the touch on a mobile phone

partial code

```
 ratingStars = new RatingStars();
            ratingStars.setMaxValue(5);
            //The rating star widget has a function to add star specific captions, doesn't work right in iOS

                ratingStars.setValueCaption(valueCaptions.values().toArray(new String[5]));

            ratingStars.setImmediate(true);
            ratingStars.setPrimaryStyleName("pp-ratingstars-wrapper");
            ratingStars.setPrimaryStyleName("v-ratingstars-wrapper-large");
            ratingStarsList.add(ratingStars);
```

What are the possible fixes for this problem?

[image][image]

Comment: Contact the author and/or look at the source code of the addon. https://github.com/tehapo/RatingStars and http://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/72816/72815

Comment: i dont get it. I explained my question well, and ask for some possible fixes. (& I contacted the author). I didn't expect u guys to know everything. If u guys dont know the answer, then leave it. Downvote my question makes me feel like this website is full of impatience and unhelpful people who think they're expert and so busy until the point that they don't have time for others. Have u ever asked a question in ur life at all? If someone says NO, i'll admit that i am stupid

Comment: The downvote is not from me... (And I don't see a reason for the down vote)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in animation.

```
stars.setAnimated(false);
```